# Unable to post variables with jquery post()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I am trying to pass variables from a modal form to another page. I declare the variables from the form with the id tags in each selection.

Page reloads to test.php, however no variable can be echoed.

javascript

```
var id = $( "#id" ),
    name = $( "#name" )

$.post("jqtest/test.php", { device_id: "id", device_name: "name" });
load('jqtest/test.php');
```

test.php

```
echo $_POST['device_name'];
echo $_POST['device_id'];
```

Comment: This is a jumbled, tangled mess of PHP and JS. can you please separate stuff? Surely all this is not within a single JS script.

Comment: _"Page reloads to test.php"_. Are you sure you understand how AJAX works?

Comment: You have a severe misunderstanding of how the web works based on the provided example. I encourage you to go read about the client-server model and become more familiar with the distinctions between PHP and javascript before continuing.

Comment: the php is on a different page I understand the differences between the two however I am not very familiar with jscript just yet.

Also no it's not within the same page...

Comment: @elclanrs I have a basic understanding of the jquery post() function. The page is loaded from load('jqtest/test.php');

Comment: `$.post` is just a shortcut to `$.ajax` with predefined values. You should look into `$.ajax`, learn about callbacks. It's well documented on the jQuery docs.

Comment: Please show your code that deals with your modal form

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how are you planning to use this code to pass values from your modal form but there are several problems with your current code:

1. `;` is missing at the end of variable assignment
2. read values from input fields using `val()` instead of getting jquery objects of them
3. use variable names in data object of post method instead of literals ("id", "name")

Try this to see that variables are passed and echoed in a callback function

```
var id = $( "#id" ).val(),
    name = $( "#name" ).val();

$.post("jqtest/test.php", 
       { device_id: id, device_name: name },
       function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a lot wrong with this... It looks like you are using `echo $_POST['device_name'];` and `echo $_POST['device_id'];` just to ensure that your AJAX is working. If that's the case, you don't need to be using `.load();`. You are also sending the jQuery object of `$( "#id" )` and `$( "#name" )` instead of the values within those form elements. Later, in your .post request, you have those same variables in quotes, which is sending the strings "id" and "name". Again - likely not what you're looking for.

Your question is a bit convoluted but I'll do my best to answer. Try this JS:

```
var id = $("#id").val(),
    name = $("#name").val();

$.post("jqtest/test.php", { device_id: id, device_name: name }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

In your PHP file, use this code:

```
echo $_POST['device_name'];
echo $_POST['device_id'];
```

You will see your variables show up in the JS console of your browser. With this script, you've sent your two variables to test.php via POST and test.php will echo the results. The callback function added to the $.post request will display the output from test.php in the javascript console. Learn more about `.$post()` on the [jQuery docs.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)